# How can I create an animation in CSS and JavaScript by using graph equation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

Creating complex animations with pure CSS takes me time and probably 100s lines of code. So my question is **how can I create an animation in CSS and JavaScript by using graphs equation**? As we know that you can create any shape, size or figure equation in graph, for example this is a graph of *y=-|sin(x)|*:

[image]

If I want the animation which is similar to this graph (where 0 < x < pi):

[image]

I just take different values of x & y and put the values in my CSS animation code:

```css
div {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes example {
  5%  {left:15.7079632679px; top:15.643446504px;}
  10% {left:31.4159265359px; top:30.9016994375px;}
  15% {left:47.1238898038px; top:45.399049974px;}
  20% {left:62.8318530718px; top:58.7785252292px;}
  25% {left:78.5398163397px; top:70.7106781187px;}
  30% {left:94.2477796077px; top:80.9016994375px;}
  35% {left:109.955742876px; top:89.1006524188px;}
  40% {left:125.663706144px; top:95.1056516295px;}
  45% {left:141.371669412px; top:98.7688340595px;}
  50% {left:157.079632679px; top:100px;}
  55% {left:172.787595947px; top:98.7688340595px;}
  60% {left:188.495559215px; top:95.1056516295px;}
  65% {left:204.203522483px; top:89.1006524188px;}
  70% {left:219.911485751px; top:80.9016994375px;}
  75% {left:235.619449019px; top:70.7106781187px;}
  80% {left:251.327412287px; top:58.7785252292px;}
  85% {left:267.035375555px; top:45.399049974px;}
  90% {left:282.743338823px; top:30.9016994375px;}
  95% {left:298.451302091px; top:15.643446504px;}
  100% {left:314.159265359px; top:0px;}
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

But when the animation is complicated it takes too much time to write all these values, as you can see in this graph: [image]

Is it efficient to create a JavaScript where I just put the equation and the range of that equation, so that it automatically takes different vales of x and y and performs the animation accordingly?

[image]

The biggest advantage of this is that you can easily create any type of complex animations by just putting the equation of that animation in that script.

Comment: More efficient for you, or more efficient for the browser?

Comment: @ Mike_McCaughan i guess it is efficient for me but what about,- for browser

Answer (score 1):

I hope I can answer,

But yes I guess it would be more efficient in javascript as instead of plotting individual values of x and y for your animation, you can just use a for loop and increment by however little you want (For smoothness). So like:

```
for(var i  = 0; i < (Whatever range you want); i + your increment){
animation code
}
```

Answer to second question: Yes it will be more efficient.